# Computing an Analytic Function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been working on a problem and I just can not seem to get my algebra right, so I've come for some help. I've got $u(x,y)=(x+4)(y-3)$, and from there found the harmonic conjugates  $v(x,y)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2}-3y-3x,$
and thus have $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are given here.

I want to compute the analytic function $f(z)$ in terms of $z$, not $x$ and $y$, using
$$x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\qquad y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$$
Once I exchange all values of $x$ and $y$, I have tried some basic manipulation and factoring out both the $z$'s and the $\bar{z}$'s, and I'm not quite getting there.

Can $f(z)$ have *any* $\bar{z}$'s in it, or would that immediately render it non-analytic?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is your eighth question on this site, and still no MathJax at all? I suggest you look at exactly how Alakatos fixed up your post so nicely, by clicking "edited $n$ minutes ago"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want an expression with no $\bar{z}$.  All the $\bar{z}$'s should cancel.

Hint: the imaginary part of $z^2$ is $2 x y$.  So the real part of $\ldots$ is $xy$.

Answer (score 1):

$((y^2-x^2)/2)-3y-3x$ is not the harmonic conjugate of $(x+4)(y-3)$.

Find the right harmonic conjugate and the substitutions $x = \dfrac{z+\bar z}{2}$ and $y=\dfrac{z-\bar z}{2 i}$ in the expression $u+iv$ will give you the function you're looking for.

And please, learn to use MathJax.